# Is it possible for us to download a file to a sandboxed location using File API available in HTML 5?

Tags: html, fileapi

I wanted to ensure the documents I let user download are programmatically manipulated throughout program.

I came to know that [File API](http://dev.w3.org/2009/dap/file-system/pub/FileSystem/) does give Apps the opportunity to manipulate them. But how can we store the Files in the sandboxed location?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot directly read or write anything to the file system. You always have to go through either the usual upload/save dialog, or rely on desktop drag-and-drop (you can drag files *into* most modern browsers, and *out of* Google Chrome, at least).

Comment: But how  does the CLoud Reader App of Amazon work then? It should be storing some docs in the browser right?

Comment: @Krishnan Oh, if you’re just looking to store data in the browser, check out HTML5 local storage. Here’s a nice introduction: http://diveintohtml5.org/storage.html

Comment: But can we store a pdf or office document..And I also wwant to ensure user dont have access to it..

Comment: You could use base 64 encoding to store binary objects. The user is not going to notice you are storing anything in their browser, any more than you notice cookies. However, if you want to *ensure* that the user doesn’t have access to the data, you will have to use encryption.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you can't let the browser download the file directly into File API's sandbox now. You have to fetch the file by yourself in JavaScript and write it to a file through File API. If the file is from the same origin, you can just fetch it by XHR.

Comment: Thanks Cat Chen.. But how can secure it?

Comment: Do you mean the security of sandboxed files?